# Remove comments from XHTML using XSLT

Tags: xpath, xhtml, xslt-1.0

How can i remove commented lines from XHTML using XSLT ,

Example : test.xtml

```
<html>
    <head/>
        <body>
             This is Test Code.  
             <!--Test Comment -->   
        </body>
</html>
```

XSLT :: The below XSLT gives warning " Severity: warning Description: Ambiguous rule match for  html[1]/body[1]/comment()[1] Matches both "comment()" on line 10 of remove_comment.xsl
and "node()|@*" on line 4 of remove_comment.xsl "

```
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the template on line 10 with `match="comment()"` a higher priority e.g. `<xsl:template match="comment()" priority="5"/>`.